# Python Socket Client Disappears, Server Can Not Tell

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

I'm going crazy writing a little socket server in python.  Everything was working fine, but I noticed that in the case where the client just disappears, the server can't tell.  I simulate this by pulling the ethernet cable between the client and server, close the client, then plug the cable back in.  The server never hears that the client disconnected and will wait forever, never allowing more clients to connect.

I figured I'd solve this by adding a timeout to the read loop so that it would try and read every 10 seconds.  I thought maybe if it tried to read from the socket it would notice the client was missing.  But then I realized there really is no way for the server to know that.

So I added a heartbeat.  If the server goes 10 seconds without reading, it will send data to the client.  However, even this is successful (meaning doesn't throw any kind of exception).  So I am able to both read and write to a client that isn't there any more.  Is there any way to know that the client is gone without implementing some kind of challenge/response protocol between the client and server?  That would be a breaking change in this case and I'd like to avoid it.

Here is the core of my code for this:

```
  def _loop(self):
      command = ""
      while True:
          socket, address = self._listen_socket.accept()
          self._socket = socket
          self._socket.settimeout(10)
          socket.sendall("Welcome\r\n\r\n")
          while True:
              try:
                  data = socket.recv(1)
              except timeout: # Went 10 seconds without data
                  pass
              except Exception as e: # Likely the client closed the connection
                 break
             if data:
                 command = command + data
                 if data == "\n" or data == "\r":
                     if len(command.strip()) > 0:
                         self._parse_command(command.strip(), socket)
                         command = ""
                 if data == '\x08':
                     command = command[:-2]
             else: # Timeout on read
                 try:
                     self._socket.sendall("event,heartbeat\r\n") # Send heartbeat
                 except:
                     self._socket.close()
                     break
```

The sendall for the heartbeat never throws an exception and the recv only throws a timeout (or another exception if the client properly closes the connection under normal circumstances).

Any ideas?  Am I wrong that sending to a client that doesn't ACK should generate an exception eventually (I've tested for several minutes).

Comment: It should fail........  eventually... when the system is reasonably sure that no viable route exists.  Since a viable link may involve nasties like dial-up modems or carrier pigeons, this can take a long time.    As you suspect, application-level poll/ack is usually used to monitor reachability during 'quiet' intervals when no other data is exchanged between peers.

Comment: Also 'The server never hears that the client disconnected and will wait forever, never allowing more clients to connect.' - points to a serious problem with your server design.  One stuck/AWOL client should not prevent others from connecting/communicating!

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you are observing is the expected behavior for a TCP socket connection.  In particular, in general the TCP stack has no way of knowing that an ethernet cable has been pulled or that the (now physically disconnected) remote client program has shut down; all it knows is that it has stopped receiving acknowledgement packets from the remote peer, and for all it knows the packets could just be getting dropped by an overloaded router somewhere and the issue will resolve itself momentarily.  Given that, it does what TCP always does when its packets don't get acknowledged:  it reduces its transmission rate and its number-of-packets-in-flight limit, and retransmits the unacknowledged packets in the hope that they will get through this time.

Assuming the server's socket has outgoing data pending, the TCP stack will eventually (i.e. after a few minutes) decide that no data has gone through for a long-enough time, and unilaterally close the connection.  So if you're okay with a problem-detection time of a few minutes, the easiest way to avoid the zombie-connection problem is simply to be sure to periodically send a bit of heartbeat data over the TCP connection, as you described.  When the TCP stack tries (and repeatedly fails) to get the outgoing data sent-and-acknowledged, that is what eventually will trigger it to close the connection.

If you want something quicker than that, you'll need to implement your own challenge/response system with timeouts (either over the TCP socket, or over a separate TCP socket, or over UDP), but note that in doing so you are likely to suffer from false positives yourself (e.g. you might end up severing a TCP connection that was not actually dead but only suffering from a temporary condition of lost packets due to congestion).  Whether or not that's a worthwhile tradeoff depends on what sort of program you are writing.  (Note also that UDP has its own issues, particularly if you want your system to work across firewalls, etc)